# Python group similar lines in file onto one line

Tags: python, file, sorting

i currently have a file that is very unordered

```
file.txt

vfc1 3435 4556
vfc1 2334 2123
vfc1 5556 1234
vfc2 8997 5969
vfc2 4543 3343
vfc2 1232 2123
```

What i would like to do is order this file so that all the lines in my file appear on one line to look like this:

```
file_output.txt
vfc1 1234 2123 2334 3435 4556 5556 
vfc2 1232 2123 3343 4543 5969 8997
```

Comment: Take a stab at it. Use a dictionary.

Comment: In your example, all `vfc1`s go before all `vfc2`s, so it's in a way ordered, is that on purpose?

Comment: @Blender i have taken a stab at it.. using a dictionary, the results was awful. also i have never played with dictionaries before

Comment: @Blender Ok. but this is not the best:::

d = {}

with open("temp.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
       value = line.split()
       key = value[0]
       val2 = value[1]
       val3 = value[2]
       d[str(key)] = val2 +' '+val3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data = line.split()
        d[data[0]].extend(data[1:])

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        f.write(
            '%(key)s %(value)s\n' 
            % {'key': key, 'value': " ".join(sorted(value))}
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
d = {}

for line in file('file.txt'):
        if line.strip():
                sl = line.split()
                if d.has_key(sl[0]):
                        d[sl[0]] += ' %s' % ' '.join(sl[1:])
                else:
                        d[sl[0]] = ' '.join(sl[1:])

fd = open('file_output.txt', 'w')
for key in d:
        fd.write('%s %s\n' % (key, d[key]))

fd.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not python-specific. More like pseudocode, but here's the idea :

- Get all lines in an array
- Set a target array
- Set a "last entry" array
- Set a global var to determine the current Index
- Go through the array :

  - Split the string using `' '`(space) as the delimiter, into array `parts`
  - Is `parts[0]`==currentIndex? If yes, add `parts[1],parts[2]` to `lastEntry`.
  - If NOT, add `lastEntry` to `targetArray`. Set `currentIndex = parts[0]`. Clear `lastEntry`. Add `parts[1],parts[2]` to `lastEntry`.

And that's it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_file = open('file.txt', 'r')

lines = {}

for line in my_file:
    values = line.split()
    lines[values[0]] = lines.get(values[0], []) + values[1:]

my_file.close()
new_file = open('output_file.txt', 'w')

for k in lines:
    line = '%s %s\n' % (k, ' '.join(sorted(lines[k])))
    new_file.write(line)

new_file.close()
```

Comment: I get errors with this code. it says:

TypeError: values() takes no arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `iterools.groupby` to group lines by first column:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain, groupby

with open(input) as f:
    data = (x.split() for x in f)
    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    for key, group in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        for line in group:
            grouped[key] += line[1:]

for k,v in grouped.items():
    print k, ' '.join(v)
```